# MariaDB: delete row by using table alias doesn´t work

Tags: mariadb, alias

having a statement like this:

> DELETE FROM ek_stockvalue lw WHERE lw.id_stockvalue = 6

seems to run in an error in MariaDB. If i remove the "lw"-tablealias, it works:

> DELETE FROM ek_stockvalue WHERE id_stockvalue = 6

Answer (score 3):

In MariaDB's documentation nothing is mentioned, see [DELETE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/delete/), however, in MySQL's documentation the following is indicated, see [13.2.2 DELETE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html):

> **Note**
>
> If you declare an alias for a table, you must use the alias when
>   referring to the table:
>
> `DELETE t1 FROM test AS t1, test2 WHERE ...`

Try:

```sql
DELETE `lw` FROM `ek_stockvalue` `lw`
WHERE `lw`.`id_stockvalue` = 6;
```

See [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=9b350229b25909deb95a448348259699).

Answer (score 0):

Nest a select statement into your delete statement like this (where I assume that your table has an identifying column named 'id'). Then you can use alias within the select statement:

```
DELETE FROM ek_stockvalue WHERE id in (
    SELECT id FROM ek_stockvalue lw WHERE lw.id_stockvalue = 6
)
```